# View message in website to mobile Browsers

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, dialog

How to display a message on website to mobile Browsers that disappears after a short time use `jquery-mobile`

Such as gmail show when you perform the download of attachment 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

hm.. quickshot:

```
var shortTime = 5; // for 5 seconds
$('body').on("yourevent",function(e) {
    $('body').append($("<div id="startDl">Starting download</div>"));
    setTimeout(function(e) {
        $('body').remove($("#startDl"));
    }, shortTime);
});
```

there are still better ways.. e.g. remove the element after callback of your function startDownload() or whatever..

Comment: @lealam could i help you?